# Style Advice for Custom Services in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in Angular JS. And I am creating a custom service in it.

```js
  var myApp = angular
            .module("myModule", [])
            .controller("myController", function ($scope, stringService) {
                $scope.callMe = function (input) {
                    $scope.wish= stringService.processFunction(input);
                };
            });


myApp.factory('stringService', function () {
        return {
            processFunction: function(input){
                //Manipulate you data here.
                return "Hello " + input;
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="JavaScriptCusomServiceMain.js"></script>
        <script src="JavaScriptCustomService.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="wish" />
        <input type="button" value="Click Here" ng-click="callMe(name)" />
        <br />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why do we have to give same name "myApp" in both the javascript code?

Comment: In your case, `myApp` is a reference to the Angular module `myModule`. Then `myApp.factory` means you're creating a factory related to that module. You could also use the syntax `angular.module('myModule').factory(...)` which is best practice afaik since it helps keep the global namespace cleaner

Comment: That means I have to compulsorily give that "myApp" name to variable if I want to use that service.

Comment: No - as I said, you can use the `angular.module('myModule').factory(...)` syntax in which case you dont need to use a global variable

Comment: That I got what you told. I was telling that for what code I have posted. Thanx.

Comment: Read [AngularJS styleguide (ES2015)](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide).

Answer (score 3):

`myApp` holds the reference to the module you defined using `angular.module('modulename', []);`

if you want to get the same module reference again without existing variable you can do so by using `.module` method without second argument, when second argument `dependency` is present it defines module and if second argument is not given it returns the module which is already defined so doing like below is also valid

```
angular
  .module("myModule").service('stringService', function{/** return object of factory **/});
```

and above can go in seperate file as well, but make sure the file which defines module should be included first otherwise angular will give error about module is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sam answer, note the difference between:

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
```

and:

```
angular.module("myModule")
```

With a second argument (an array of dependencies), you *declare* a module. Without the dependencies argument, you get *a reference to an already-defined module*. Mixing the two forms might yield cryptic errors.